# Show that $\mathbb Q_S$ is a subring of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: number-theory

Let $T$ be any set of prime numbers and let $\mathbb Q_T$ denote the set of rationals $x$ such that when $x$ is written as $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q$ coprime then all the prime factors of $q$ are in $T$. I need to show that $\mathbb Q_T$ is a subring of $\mathbb Q$.

$1\in \mathbb Q_T$ as $1=\frac{1}{1}$, $1$ is coprime with itself and all its prime factors (which is nothing) are in $\mathbb Q_S$.

Now suppose  $p,q\in \mathbb Q_S$. Then $p=\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{b_1^{n_1}...b_k^{n_k}}$ for some coprime $a,b$ and $b_i\in S$ are the prime factors of $b$. Similarly $q=\displaystyle\frac{c}{d}=\frac{c}{d_1^{m_1}...d_l^{m_l}}$ for some coprime $c,d$ and $d_i\in S$ are the prime factors of $d$.

I can see why $pq$ and $p-q$ are in $\mathbb Q_S$, as the denominator of each is just the product of the prime factors, but how can I justify it? Is this all I need to do to show that it is a subring?

Comment: Note that if $\frac{r}{s}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and all prime factors of $s$ lie in $T$, then $\frac{r}{s}\in \mathbb{Q}_T$, **even** if $r$ and $s$ are not coprime. Because you can write $\frac{r}{s}$ as $\frac{a}{b}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and you will have $br=as$. So $b|as$, and therefore $b|s$ (since $\gcd(b,a)=1$). Thus, all prime factors of $b$ are prime factors of $s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see why $pq$ and $p-q$ are in $\mathbb Q_S$, as the denominator of each is just the product of the prime factors, but how can I justify it?

Depending on how much explanation is required, the argument you just sketched may actually be sufficient as a proof.

> Is this all I need to do to show that it is a subring?

Yes. A subset of a ring that contains $1$ and is stable under multiplication and subtraction, is a subring. It would however be good to mention this fact, in order to demonstrate that you are aware of it.

Comment: Why do we show closure under subtraction rather than addition like vector spaces?

Comment: Because we want every element to have an additive inverse. (check that this indeed follows from closedness under subtraction). In vector spaces, additive inverse is automatic, once we require closedness under scalar multiplication. The additive inverse of $v$ is $(-1) \cdot v$.